# Bluetooth driver for Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth is not getting installed?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bluetooth-3.0

[image]

My OS is 64 bit Windows 7 ultimate.

I tried many drivers for the INTEL ac7260 dual band wifi + bluetooth card but not able to get this done.

Comment: You need to install Windows 7 Service Pack 1 or upgrade to Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10 to install this device driver.

Comment: Have you made sure you have SP1 installed as per the requirements in the error message? Start > Control Panel > System should say "Service Pack 1" in the "Windows Edition" section.